# VOIP Gateway: Asterisk or FreeSwitch

Tags: asterisk, freeswitch

I would like to have a VOIP Gateway server to route/control calls from public site to internal network and vise versa. What I know of is Asterisk and FreeSwitch, can handle this job. But in term of functionality and security, I am confusing either to make a decision between Asterisk or FreeSwitch.  Or if you know any other software can take care of this job better, please help me!
please help me to pick a good one!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk: more online resources, high level features

FreeSwitch: more stable, higher performance

It usually comes down to the SIP stack. FreeSwitch uses Sofia from the start, Asterisk had it's own implementation for a while (chan_sip, deprecated), but integrated PJSIP just a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Question about recommend to select tool is offtopic on SO.

Asterisk simpler to configure, simple to find developer/help, simple install for begginner(have ISO like elastic).

Freeswitch have slightly better source code(becuase it NEWER). Slightly better perfomance(only if you use default setting for asterisk and default settings for freeswitch, for advanced use perfomance same)

Security depend of your skill and confidence with switch as primary, not depend much of solution you use.

Yes, i know other software. Kamailio/opensips will work "better"(can handle 5000calls+).But much more complex to setup and maintain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Arheops. As you have mentioned above about Kamailio/opensips, I will consider to learn that one.